# Inject embedded code block html in asp.net pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I need to inject embedded code block (<%= %>) in html and render when page is load. This can later on call the actual `getData()` function to render image.

Here is the example:

`default.aspx`

```
<div id="divImage" runat="Server" />
```

`default.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // There will be list of ids that has assing images. 
  divImage.InnerHtml = "<h3>Hello World</h3> <img src=\"<%= getData(id) %>\"";
}

public string getData(string id)
{
   return _client.GetImage(id); //"https://test.com/test-{id}.jpg";
}
```

Above code render code block as it is in HTML and doesn't make call to function.

Comment: You can't just embed Web Forms markup in HTML and expect it to work. That HTML is rendered on the client, meaning it doesn't go through the Web Forms engine.

Comment: Why not add an <asp:Image> control and set the ImageUrl via code behind?

Comment: @mason, In this code, it's injecting huge HTML code. It has `<img>` tag in it. I need to do is read the images after page load. I was thinking to do it as above example.

Comment: <% %> is valid in the markup (code « like » HTML) but not in the code behind (C# code). In code behind, the correct syntax is <img src=\"" + getData(id) + "\"" But the suggestion of @mason is the correct approach.

Comment: this `<%= getData(id) %>`  works only direct on html page - not if you place it as string... "This can later on call"... to make later call, use ajax

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  divImage.InnerHtml = "<h3>Hello World</h3> <img src='" + getData() + "'";
}
```

Comment: In here, `getData()` getting called whenever server assign html to `InnerHtml` property . I  needed to render this method after page is load.